# Google+ Sign In on Android 'Internal Error occurred'

Tags: android, google-plus

I've spent hours trying to get Google+ sign in to work on my Android app.  I've read through all ~20 posts on this topic on StackOverflow, but none of the solutions have solved my problem.  This is what I've tried:

- I've set the correct SHA1 key and package name (Google Play Maps works fine in my app) in the credentials section of the API console
- I've turned on the Google+ API and setup the consent screen in the API console
- am using the [sample code](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android) from the SDK
- read the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android) and [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in)
- have turned on verbose logging for Google Play

but I keep getting "internal error occurred" messages, and the log says:
onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = 4
which indicates "SIGN_IN_REQUIRED", but no dialog to sign in or select an account shows up on my device (Nexus 4, running Android 4.4.2).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Well I can't offer you any help as I am getting the exact same problem! I am using Android Studio, using the exact sample by downloading it from GIT. Using the correct pacakge name and using the SHA1 that was provided for me from running the command prompt key command. Its really annoying!!! I have deleted and re-added the info in the developer console a number of times but nothing.

Comment: Solved! You have to fill in the info on the consent screen in the console

Comment: Hey Martin, I've already added the product name, email address, homepage, and logo on the consent screen - but it still isn't working.  What did you have to fill in on the consent screen?  And what link did you use to download it from GIT?  thanks

Comment: I filled in the email address, all fields unless they said Optional and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tel you something that happens quite often. When you copy the SHA1 and the app package name in the required fields of the create client id form from the dev console, be dead sure that you didn't copy a space too in one of that fields. This is what happened to me. I've spent several hours on searching the web up and down for info about the ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = 4 but was in vain. Than I've thought that it would be worth creating a new client ID from scratch and than I noticed that I was copying a space after the app package name.

Also you'll need to create a new client ID if you rethink and change the app package.
Maybe you're problem is solved but I hope this answer will help others that wonder here.